# Unable to Add Value to a Function & Stop Request from executing (POSTMAN)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, api, postman

**I'm pretty new to POSTMAN and also looking for other ways to write this function. Any additional ways is much appreciative.**

Below is a 200 Status OK test in POSTMAN.  If the status does not come back as 200 Status OK, I'd like to tally/count that failure as a value(+1).  In a later request, an Else/if condition (below) will check how many failures are there. And if failures >0 then that will trigger a new request.

BUT If this test were to have a status(400) and not a 200, meaning it would fail how can I tell it to count that failure(+1) as a value?

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("failures", []);
let failures = pm.collectionVariables.get("failures")

pm.test("Status test", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

Below is a pre-script request in POSTMAN.  As I mentioned above, if there is a value greater than 0 for failures, then run a "New Request".  If not, do nothing.  I think I have this else/if statement correct.  Just including it for your reference.

```
let failures = pm.collectionVariables.get("failures")
console.log(failures)
if (failures.length >0) {
    console.log('failures found')
    pm.sendRequest("New Request")
} else {
    console.log('NO failures')
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
    return null
}
```

(Screen shots - Unable to stop request from executing)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the `failures` like this:

```
let failures = pm.environment.get("failures");

if (failures === undefined || failures === null){
    failures = 0;
    pm.environment.set("failures", failures);
}

pm.test("Status test", function () {
    if (pm.response.code !== 200){
        failures += 1;
        pm.environment.set("failures", failures)
    }
    pm.response.to.have.status(200);
});
```

Code to check would be:

```
let failures = pm.environment.get("failures")

if (failures > 0) {
    console.log('failures found')
    postman.setNextRequest("New Request")

    //you can reset failures if needed.
    pm.environment.set("failures", 0)

} else {
    console.log('NO failures')
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

Comment: Hey @lucasnguyen17 - appreciate the answer. however, it doesn't seem to be working.  It's sending a "New Request" if there are failures or no failures   I'm thinking it may have something to do with the collection object?

Comment: Are you sure about that? Can you take a screenshot, I’d like to take a look.

Comment: Added a few photos, w/ your code.  2 Test Request then a 1 Final request thats suppose to check the failures and run the 'New Request' if there are greater than 0 failures.  But as you can see on the screen shot, in the log, running this collection passed but the log shows failures found and the "New Request" was sent...

Comment: @BillZ sorry, my bad. I've updated the answer, please check it.

Comment: Ran it, still sends request even if No failures.  This time it does indeed saying 'NO failures' in the log but still is sending the request.  After some research found some info under 'Stop Workflow Execution' on https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/building-workflows/

Let me know what you think...

Comment: It’s kind of late in my timezone, I will comeback tomorrow. I think I can fix your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236376/discussion-between-lucasnguyen17-and-bill-z).